# How do I force an enemy to surrender and accept my demands?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I am totally stumped this OFTEN happens;
 I'm at war and the enemy has one county. I have successfully seiged all holdings in this county but the enemy (in this case the chieftess of Rogaland)  still refuses to peace with enforced demands. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In order to enforce demands, you generally need to have 100% warscore.

> Warscore can be gained in four ways:
>
> Winning battles against enemy armies.
>
> Sieging down and occupying enemy holdings.
>
> In some Casus Bellis, the warscore will tick up or down if the targeted province is fully in the attacker's or defender's hands.
>
> Holding prisoners. If the leader of a war is captured, warscore becomes 100% in his enemy's favour. Captured close relatives of the war leader also affect the war score.
>
> Warscore gains from victories in battle or from occupying holdings are larger if they're against the war leader as opposed to his allies. Battles have half their usual warscore value in crusades.

If your war score is still not 100% after occupying all their visible holdings, they might have holdings you do not know about.

Source: http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Warfare

Comment: thanks, actually i think they had a prisoner but they refused to release them so i couldnt finish the war. they only had one county, but maybe there was an army somewhere on map how would i ever find it if it's hiding somewhere...so i lost war. Now I tryng to work out how to use ships they are so frustrating the interface is very fiddly for ships. often they just refuse to go close to land so i cannot embark or disembark troups!! how can i then attck island counties?

Comment: I would reccomend making that a separate question for a better answer, but you can click on the land from the boat and your fleet will move to the coast where you can disembark.

Comment: For coasts that are not part of your realm you won't be able to directly disembark, but you'll need to click on the army on the ships(on the side of the fleet window that's open when you click on it) and manually set them to move to land.